# Fancybox WordPress Plugin not Wrapping overlay div to image content

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, fancybox

I'm experiencing a weird glitch in the [Fancybox for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/fancybox-for-wordpress/) plugin on [Los del Patio's testing home page](http://testing.losdelpatio.org/).

I'm trying to get the featured image to be pulled into a fancybox. The featured image exists as a hidden div that get's display:visible and fancyboxed. It works except the wrapping div doesn't match the image's dimensions. I've even followed the instructions to override by calling out an inline width and height for the container div that's hidden.

Here's the screenshot of what's happening:

[image: screenshot of fancybox wrapping bug]

Here's the code from my page-casa.phtml template:

```
    <aside class="galeria-preview" role="complementary">
        <h2><a class="fancybox" href="#galeria-img">Pr&oacute;ximo Exposici&oacute;n: <br/>
        <span class="verde"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'galeria-proximo',true); ?></span></a></h2> 
        <div style="width:940px;height:400px;" id="galeria-img" class="hidden">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' ); ?> 
        </div>
    </aside>
```

Thanks for any help peeps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to go directly without using a plugin for this.

I had a resizing problem like yours. I coded and searched a lot for it and finally moved to this [pirobox](http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/#howto) that has autoresing and my problem solved...

Comment: Got it installed, even has a WP Plugin now for pirobox. Thanks!